# Spring configuration metadata in multi-module project not picked up by IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, kotlin, kapt

I have the following multi-module layout:

```
rootProject
├── subProject library
└── subProject application
```

The library contains `@ConfigurationProperties` and has dependencies on the required stuff to generate the `spring-configuration-metadata.json` file. All of this works perfectely. The application has a dependency on the library and it can find the classes in there, autowiring with Spring works, … well, everything works.

However, IntelliJ does not pick up the `spring-configuration-metadata.json` file from the library and as a consequence does not recognize those options in the `application.yml` file of the application.

> How can I make IntelliJ aware of additional `spring-configuration-metadata.yml` files that it should load?

Answer (score 3):

This should work. Could you please create an issue here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach a minimal sample project as ZIP (you can set visibility to 'idea-developers' to make it private). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround to add `spring-boot-configuration-processor` to second module (even when you dont have there any `@ConfigurationProperties` POJOs)

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

And I have created issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-232629